# Jabref ordering Latex bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

I write the bibliography in Jabref using `bibtexkey` as a reference. When I call it in LaTeX using `\cite{1}`, in the PDF file I have [9].

The problem is that I can't arrange an order to the references. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: JabRef doesn't influence the ordering of the references at all, the bibliography style decides that. Most styles organize references alphabetically I believe, while e.g. `unsrt` sorts them after order of citation.

Comment: The order (and the naming of the keys) in jabref is irrelevant. It doesn't matter if you use `\cite{blub}`, `\cite{a}` or `\cite{47}`: The output and order in latex will depend on your bibliographystyle.

Comment: I had the same issue mentioned in the original question. That issue was solved by putting _biblatex_ package **after** _hyperref_ package.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the BibTex keys as final numeric references in text.

Is better left to JabRef generate automatically meaningful author-year BibTeX keys like  `Smith2005` instead of simple numbers. As commented by Torbjørn and Ulrike Fischer, the final reference number in the PDF is not the BibTeX key. According to the  bibliography style, the number of the reference citation could be order of citation in article, and the  bibliography is ordered by this number. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   text \cite{Solano2009}
   text \cite{Miro2008} 
   text \cite{Morales2012}
   text \cite{Arce2013} 
   text \cite{Pennisi2013} 
   text \cite{Miro2008} 
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

This should produce in the PDF:

```
 text [1] text [2] text [3] text [4] text [5] text [2]

 References 

 [1] Solano, A ... 
 [2] Miro, G.  ...
 ....
```

But the instead of IEEEtrans, if you use the `plain` style the is number reference is the position in the alphabetically ordered references:

```
text [5] text [2] text [3] text [1] text [4] text [2]

References

[1] Arce .....
[2] Miro ...
...
```

And using the style `alpha` you can have the biobliography  alphabetically ordered with references in text based in authors and years, but unrelated with the BibTeX keys. For example, a paper of Pennisi, Hartmann and Lloid in 2013 with the key `Pennisi2013`  generate the reference `[PHIL+13]` based in the initials of the three authors and the year, so that the results is some like:

```
text [SGKM+09] text [MCP+08] text [MYMMDS+12] text [AEO+13] text
[PHL+13] text [MCP+08]

References

[AEO+13] Arce, ... 
[MCP+08] Miro ...
...
```